# Is it possible to Arcane Shift into an Essence Flux fired by myself and gain the attack speed buff?

Tags: league-of-legends

I tried it out but I think that I'm not quick enough. Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Essence Flux cannot affect Ezreal, whether you arcane shift or flash into it.

Source: [lolwiki](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Ezreal/Ability_Details)

Answer (score 0):

It will not affect ez with the buff. Even if you somehow manage to flash perfectly into it which I've almost done once.

Comment: Hi DizzyMane. We try to avoid duplicate answers here on Arqade, and it seems to me like your answer is no different from the answer Brian posted 4 days ago.